# Lipschitz function without Lipschitz-like increments

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, bounded-variation, rough-path-theory, p-variation

Claim: Let $V: [0, T] (\subset \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function, i.e. $$|V(x,y)|:=|V(x)-V(y)| \leq K_1 | x - y |$$ for all $x,y$ in $[0, T]  $, where $V(.,.)$ denotes the difference between values of $V$. Then, it follows that the difference satisfies a Lipschitz-like condition, i.e that there exists $K_2$ such that, for all $x,y,x’,y’$ in $\mathbb{R}$,

$$ | V(x,y) - V(x’,y’)| \\
\leq K_2 | ( x - y) - (x’- y’) |$$

**I know there is a chance this may be false from academic** *vox populi*, **can you find a counterexample?**

This post here is a follow-up to this question, so more background can be found there. I believe this specific case is more tractable: [How to prove Lipschitz functions are not Lipschitz in the $p$-variation metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266346/how-to-prove-lipschitz-functions-are-not-lipschitz-in-the-p-variation-metric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $y'=-x, x'=-y$. Then the inequality you want is $|V(x)-V(y)-V(-y)+V(-x)| \leq 0$. This is false for $V(x)=|x|$, for example.

Comment: that is great… I tried to simplify the question in the below link and over-shot: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266346/how-to-prove-lipschitz-functions-are-not-lipschitz-in-the-p-variation-metric

Comment: here is the motivating question should you be interested… https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266832/are-lipschitz-functions-lipschitz-like-in-p-variation